# Why does jQuery mouseenter / leave animate twice?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseevent

I've got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.first').mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).animate({
             top: '115px'
         }, 500 );
     });
     $('.first').mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).animate({
         top: '127px'
         }, 500 );
     });
 });
```

And when I run it my .first div goes up and down at least twice if not more and I don't know why this could be.

Thanks

Comment: When you change `top`, does the div move far enough away where the mouse leaves the div area?

Comment: you need to show us the dom :)

Comment: you should `stop()` the animation queue in this instance before adding a new animation. `$(this).stop().animate(...`

Comment: Robert, you are totally right, I should have thought of that!

Comment: the animation on enter will cause the element to move away from the mouse and thus trigger the out event.. and repeat...as it moves under/away from the mouse

Comment: and shmiddty gots the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop the animation queue before adding more animations if you don't want them to build up: http://jsfiddle.net/bgjxk/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.first').mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).stop().animate({
             top: '115px'
         }, 500 );
     });
     $('.first').mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).stop().animate({
         top: '127px'
         }, 500 );
     });
});​
```

You could also use CSS3 transitions to accomplish the same thing, more smoothly, without worrying about animation queues: http://jsfiddle.net/bgjxk/1/

```
.first{
    ...
    position:absolute;
    top:127px;
    transition:top .25s linear; /* use them vendor prefixes */
}
.first:hover{
    top:115px;
}
```